# Passing a json file to a method in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file on my computer that I need to pass to the following function:

```
def read_json(file):
    try:
        logging.debug('Reading from input')
        return read_json_from_string(json.load(file))
    finally:
        logging.debug('Done reading')
```

How can I move a file from my computer to a method in python? I have tried the following:

```
file = os.path.abspath('theFile.json')
```

Then attempting to run the method as

```
read_json(file)
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: expected file
```

I also tried:

```
file = open('theFile.json', 'r')
```

But I always get an error related to the 'file' not being a file.

Comment: Try writing the full path to the file (or a path relative to the program), not just the name. Otherwise, how can your program possibly know where it's located?

Answer (score 3):

=====UPDATED=====

Now includes an example of calling the function

---

Try something like:

```
import logging
import json

def read_json(file):
    try:
        print('Reading from input')
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            return json.load(f)
    finally:
        print('Done reading')

return_dict = read_json("my_file.json")
print return_dict
```

Comment: This one gives me: TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Comment: You're probably passing in a file object.  I've updated the answer to include an example of calling the function; hopefully that will help get things working for you.

Comment: thank you for the update. The update now gives this: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: That error happens when the file you are trying to read does not actually contain JSON text; the `json.load()` function found your file, but was unable to parse the file as it contains either no JSON or badly-formed JSON.

Comment: Is there any chance that you can include the file (or a part of the file) that you are trying to parse?  That would help us figure out why the file is not able to be parsed correctly.

Comment: unfortunately I am unable to share the data :(

Answer (score 2):

`json.load` takes a file-like object, and you're passing it a `str` containing the path. Try this instead:

```
path = os.path.abspath('theFile.json')
with open(path) as f:
    read_json(f)
```

Note that `json.load` returns a dictionary, not a string. Also, the `finally:` is executed even if an exception is raised in the `try:`, so you'll always log "Done reading", even if an error occurred and the read was aborted.

Comment: Now I am getting the error ValueError: Expected object or value

Comment: @Cybernetic I'm guessing that the error is in `read_json_from_string`, but it's hard to know what the issue is without a more detailed traceback.